# Stackboard for iOS wants beta testers!

Tags: app

### Screenshots

[image] [image]

### About

I'm an iOS developer who likes to make beautiful things. I'm also an avid Stack Exchange user, who has over 13k network rep. I was looking for a nice SE client for my iPhone - and I thought I could do better than the current offerings.

Meet Stackboard, my solution to this problem. It lets you keep track of all the newest questions on sites you select, and does it beautifully.

#### Pricing

I'm planning to release Stackboard as a 99¢ app on the App Store.

#### Platform

iOS. Just like it says in the title.

### Contact

I created this app, and Stack Overflow is a key contributor. Contact info? beta@erwaysoftware.com

### Code

I'll be keeping the code private for this app - but it's written in Objective C.

## Get Involved!

I'm ready for around 20 beta testers on this app - maybe more later on. I require iOS 6 and later (Even those running iOS 7 are supported!)

Go here to get started:

### [www.erwaysoftware.com/stackboard/beta](http://www.erwaysoftware.com/stackboard/beta)

I'll even make it fun. A sample version number? **v0.1 Repcap**

Comment: would you be willing to share some code, so that this can be duplicated for Android? This seems like such a cool project, but I have no iOS devices, only Android, Linux, and Windows 7

Comment: @The I'm not sure - I do hope to make a profit at some point, and my code is probably too sloppy to do any converting. Really, though, this code really wouldn't help much when converting to Android.

Comment: I guess that's true... and I just found out something else. There is already an official app for SE on android, although it is still in Alpha.